# How to query the DataGridView for the header name?

Tags: c#, linq, datagridview

I would like to query a datagridview for the header names. After I get the list, I'll loop through that for other things. Here's an example of the populated datagridview.

```
feature | serverName1 | serverName2 | serverName3
database| no          | yes         | no
apps    | yes         | no          | yes
services| yes         | yes         | yes
```

So in this example, if I was looking for what servers had a database, it would return "serverName2". Or if it had apps, it would return "serverName1, serverName3", etc. Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public string[] GetHeaders(string feature){
  var result = dataGridView1.Columns
                            .OfType<DataGridViewColumn>()
                            .Where(c=>dataGridView1.Rows
                                                   .OfType<DataGridViewRow>()
                                                   .Any(r=>r.Cells["feature"].Value.ToString() == feature) &&     
                                                   r.Cells[c.Name].Value.ToString() == "yes"))
                            .Select(c=>c.HeaderText)
                            .ToArray();                  
  return result;
}
```

Or this:

```
 public string[] GetHeaders(string feature){
    var row = dataGridView1.Rows
                           .OfType<DataGridViewRow>()
                           .FirstOrDefault(r=>r.Cells["feature"].Value.Equals(feature));
    if(row == null) return null;
    return row.Cells.OfType<DataGridViewCell>()
                    .Where(c=>c.Value.Equals("yes"))
                    .Select(c=>c.OwningColumn.HeaderText)
                    .ToArray();
 }
```

I think the latter is better.